# 「ないない」song lyrics

Tags: song-lyrics

I'm trying to get the lyrics from 「ないない」, by ReoNa, but I'm not sure what the lyrics is, since I found two versions (and a mix of those); namely, [this](https://www.uta-net.com/song/301976/), which for example has these lines:

> 灰のない深いかげばかり
>
> アイのない個体　人形みたい
>
> 曖昧なアイ　色の無い　眼(eye)
>
> 擬態　意外！他人事みたい

and [this](https://animesongz.com/lyric/5435/24143), which instead has:

> I のない　深い　影ばかり
>
> 愛のない　答え　ドールみたい
>
> 曖昧な愛　色のない愛
>
> 期待　以外　他人事みたい

If I'm hearing the audio well, the first one sounds right, for example 灰 vs 愛, 個体 vs 答え and 擬態 vs 期待, but I'm not sure.

I tried looking on Japanese sites as well, but even there I found both the versions, so I'm at a loss about what the lyrics actually is; [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M8LwhRkNaSQ) is the song, I was hoping someone could point me to the right lyrics.

(Incidentally, I'm also wondering if this this lyrics is something native Japanese would understand without ambiguity without knowing the lyrics, given the various use of /ai/, which could be read as "I", "愛" or "eye" at least; which could be an ambiguity the singer wanted.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The former version seems correct according to the official MV and large Japanese lyrics databases approved by JASRAC. From my personal experience, uta-net.com is credible in the sense that it contains official lyrics.

The latter version from animesongz.com is incomplete, has a few weird kanji usages (お影様 and 応え), and ignores creative readings such as [人形]{doll} and [眼]{eye}. The page even has an "Edit lyrics" button! I think someone who did not have access to the official lyrics tried to transcribe the song and made this.